# im building an auto crypto profit generator. i need some help making it work right. (incomplete code attached)

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, contract-debugging

to start with, im already deep into the process of creating this thing, ive already spend $1000 on this contract (dont feel bad for me, thats one paycheck and i needed to learn the deploying and upkeep processes. but the problem is, it doesnt matter what i try my contract doesnt actually execute properly despite having tried everything at this point, this new contract should retain eth in the contract itself, but ideally i want it to manage the funds directly in my wallet. basically im building a crypto loss nullifier. essentially, every time one of my tokens lose value on the market, my contract will pick up on the drop of price and it will (as fast as possible without costing large gas fees) take that coin and swap all of it for usd coin, but when the price of the target coin gains value, it will buy back into the coin for all that it can. and it will keep doing this as an attempt to make a loss into a gain. after it obtains a set ammount of the prefferred coin, it will swap 50% of that ammount for LINK token, the link token pays for the chainlink keeper. for anyone willing to help me make this thing work, in the case that i get something programmed and deployed and working well, i will send you a copy of my finished code if you played a decent part in helping me create it

this is the code currently, i havent tested this version, so practice safe programming on this one. if it works, feel free to use if on the condition that you let me know that it works. i just dont want to spend any more money on testing its functionality, im new to solidity but ive taught myself 6 different programming languages in my lifetime and im certain this one wont take me long. but i need a few pointers to finish this

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/KeeperCompatibleInterface.sol";

contract AutoTrader is KeeperCompatibleInterface {
    address private owner;
    IUniswapV2Router02 public uniswapRouter;
    AggregatorV3Interface public priceFeed;
    address public ethAddress;
    address public usdCoinAddress;
    address public linkAddress;

    uint256 private lastEthPrice;
    uint256 private lastCheckTime;

    uint256 public interval; // Interval in seconds

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Not the owner");
        _;
    }

    constructor(
        address _uniswapRouter,
        address _priceFeed,
        address _ethAddress,
        address _usdCoinAddress,
        address _linkAddress,
        uint256 _interval
    ) {
        owner = msg.sender;
        uniswapRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(_uniswapRouter);
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(_priceFeed);
        ethAddress = _ethAddress;
        usdCoinAddress = _usdCoinAddress;
        linkAddress = _linkAddress;
        interval = _interval;

        // Set initial values for the first check
        lastEthPrice = getEthPrice();
        lastCheckTime = block.timestamp;
    }

    function getEthPrice() internal view returns (uint256) {
        (, int256 price, , , ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        require(price > 0, "Invalid price");
        return uint256(price);
    }

    function swapETHtoUSD(uint256 amount) internal {
        // Approve Uniswap Router to spend ETH
        IERC20(ethAddress).approve(address(uniswapRouter), amount);

        // Specify the swap path
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = ethAddress;
        path[1] = usdCoinAddress;

        // Swap ETH to USD Coin
        uniswapRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(
            amount,
            0, // Accept any amount of USD Coin
            path,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp + 600 // 10 minute deadline
        );
    }

    function swapUSDtoETH(uint256 amount) internal {
        // Approve Uniswap Router to spend USD Coin
        IERC20(usdCoinAddress).approve(address(uniswapRouter), amount);

        // Specify the swap path
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = usdCoinAddress;
        path[1] = ethAddress;

        // Swap USD Coin to ETH
        uniswapRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(
            amount,
            0, // Accept any amount of ETH
            path,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp + 600 // 10 minute deadline
        );
    }

    function swapETHtoLink(uint256 amount) internal {
        // Approve Uniswap Router to spend ETH
        IERC20(ethAddress).approve(address(uniswapRouter), amount);

        // Specify the swap path
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = ethAddress;
        path[1] = linkAddress;

        // Swap ETH to Chainlink
        uniswapRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(
            amount,
            0, // Accept any amount of Chainlink
            path,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp + 600 // 10 minute deadline
        );
    }

    function terminate() external onlyOwner {
        // Ensure no funds are left in the contract
        require(IERC20(ethAddress).balanceOf(address(this)) == 0, "Withdraw ETH before termination");
        require(IERC20(usdCoinAddress).balanceOf(address(this)) == 0, "Withdraw USD Coin before termination");
        require(IERC20(linkAddress).balanceOf(address(this)) == 0, "Withdraw Chainlink before termination");

        // Destroy the contract and transfer any remaining ERC20 tokens to the owner
        selfdestruct(payable(owner));
    }

    receive() external payable {}

    function execute() internal {
        uint256 currentEthPrice = getEthPrice();

        // Swap to USD if the price went down
        if (currentEthPrice < lastEthPrice) {
            uint256 amountToSwap = IERC20(ethAddress).balanceOf(address(this)) - (10**17); // All but 0.5 ETH
            if (amountToSwap > 0) {
                swapETHtoUSD(amountToSwap);
            }
        }
        // Swap to ETH if the price went up
        else if (currentEthPrice > lastEthPrice) {
            uint256 amountToSwap = IERC20(usdCoinAddress).balanceOf(address(this));
            if (amountToSwap > 0) {
                swapUSDtoETH(amountToSwap);
            }

            // Check if the wallet has reached 100 ETH and swap 50% for Chainlink
            if (IERC20(ethAddress).balanceOf(address(this)) >= 100 ether) {
                amountToSwap = (50 ether) / 2; // 50% of the balance
                if (amountToSwap > 0) {
                    swapETHtoLink(amountToSwap);
                }
            }
        }

        // Update last check time and Ethereum price
        lastCheckTime = block.timestamp;
        lastEthPrice = currentEthPrice;
    }

    // Keeper compatibility functions
    function checkUpkeep(bytes calldata /* checkData */) external view override returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory /* performData */) {
        upkeepNeeded = block.timestamp >= lastCheckTime + interval;
    }

    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /* performData */) external override {
        execute();
    }

    // Public function for manual execution
    function manualExecute() external onlyOwner {
        execute();
    }
}
```

im only looking for help until i can figure out how to get the program trading directly from my metamask wallet, that way i can closely monitor the daily revenue generated by it on my phone anywhere i am. once i do that ill be making more versions of this code set to trade different altcoins like shib for different stable coins like usdc in a simmilar structure.